# JQuery change radio buttons checked state when each is selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button, toggle, checked, unchecked

I have three radio buttons in a search group: Zip, City and County. How can I toggle the checked states of all radio buttons in the group when one of them is clicked?

```
<input id="SC5_zipR" type="radio" value="" />
<input id="SC5_cityR" type="radio" value="" />
<input id="SC5_countyR" type="radio" value="" />

$("#SC5_zipR").prop('checked', true); //default checked value for zip code option
```

I am using Jquery 1.6.2. Thank you in advance,
Attila

Comment: Are you sure you want radio buttons, not checkboxes?

Comment: Yes radio buttons. These are search option radio buttons to search by zip, city or county.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them all the same name. It's usually how radio buttons are done:

```
<input id="SC5_zipR" name="sc5" type="radio" value="zip" />
<input id="SC5_cityR" name="sc5" type="radio" value="city" />
<input id="SC5_countyR" name="sc5" type="radio" value="county" />
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/9jRPc/